# Synonym request: tastypie, django-tastypie

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms, synonym-request

I noticed today that [tastypie](/questions/tagged/tastypie) and [django-tastypie](/questions/tagged/django-tastypie) don't appear to be synonyms even though they refer to the same thing.

The larger tag is [tastypie](/questions/tagged/tastypie), with 800+ questions to the ~200 on [django-tastypie](/questions/tagged/django-tastypie), but given that search will apparently work better with the django* prefix, I suggest the former is made a synonym of the latter.

Comment: I'd prefer [tag:django-tastypie] to be the main tag. This is more useful if you use `django*` wildcard favorites or searches

Comment: @MadScientist I have no strong opinion either way so if search works better that way round, sure :)